# SD card unmounted when HTC Desire is being charged (even with a "wall charger")

Tags: htc-desire, sd-card, charging

Whenever I plug in the charger into my HTC Desire (2.2) it unmounts the SD card. I can get around it when it's connected to a PC or other device via USB by selecting Charge Only again in the charge menu - it then re-mounts the SD card. However, you do not get the charge/connect as options when it's a wall charger so I cannot get around the problem (therefore losing all my apps installed on the card, music etc while it's charging).

Has anyone seen a bug (feature?) like this? I've been trying to find anything about this problem online but to no avail...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide logcat output when connecting your wall charger? Somewhere in pastebin. Last relevant lines only. http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Logcat

Comment: @Denis you'll have to explain what this is all about...

Comment: @Dmitry: Is it the original HTC charger or a third party one?

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I have an HT Desire running 2.2 and don't have that problem. It might be the cable of the charger that is incorrectly registering as being a USB connection (faulty, cheap knockoff that is incorrectly wired?) Try another charger. Blackberrys also use micro USB so ask a buddy to use their charger

Comment: It happens with several chargers I tried. Most of the time I use the one from my Plantronics bluetooth headset

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, never had that happen to me. If you can, try what pufferfish suggested - recharge with a different charger/cable (maybe ask around at work?)

Or if that isn't convenient possibly try taking out the SD-card and putting it back in? I've had my SD-card randomly unmount itself once and re-inserting it seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: I have removed the card on a number of occasions and that did not help... Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: hm, odd... another stab in the dark. Turn phone off, plug in to charge. Turn phone back on... does the SD card still get unmounted?

Comment: I will try that when I get to the charger, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer here - did not help

Answer (score 0):

Your HTC Desire is definitely has a malfunction. Try to reboot. As a workaround, you can try to configure to do nothing if USB cable is connected. Search for option in Menu => Settings or from notification when connected to PC.

Comment: It happens when a _wall charger_ is connected, not just a USB (i.e. when phone understands it's a USB connection and gives you options about what type of connection to establish)

Comment: You said "I can get around it when it's connected to a PC or other device via USB by selecting Charge Only again in the charge menu - it then re-mounts the SD card.". I believe that you have USB disk configured as default when connecting USB cable. Try and see if this settings applies when you connect your wall charger. I may apply (incorrectly) in your case, because the phone detects the charger as a USB device. Just configure "Charge only" to be the default.

Comment: Default connection type is already "Charge Only"

Answer (score 0):

Try another SD card? Maybe the problem is voltage stability...

Comment: Not sure I can get one